# Can I host a website on a different address from the webmail?

Tags: domains, dns, email

I have what is to me an unusual situation.

I have a client for whom I have built a website which I will be hosting, they have been using their domain name for their email addresses for a long period before I came along so moving their email account to my host would be problematic and building the website with their current host would also be problematic because their host is very restrictive.

So to fix this I altered the A record in their existing control panel to point the domain name to my server. As a result I can see the pages that I have created at their domain and they can still access their existing webmail.  However, it appears that they are now experiencing problems receiving email so I can only assume my solution was incorrect.

What is the correct way to point their domain at my website but keep their webmail with the existing host?

EDIT: 25/5/2012 - My client has finally responded to me after changing the MX record on their existing C-Panel. Email to their email address were being bounced back with the error 'no such recipient', so I set up the same email address in the new C-Panel and changed the MX record there to 'Remote mail exchanger' which has stopped the emails bouncing but has apparently lost them in cyperspace! Unfortunately I can't add a new record because this would require a fully qualified domain name and their domain name is of course pointed at our server!

Answer (score 2):

This shouldn't be a problem. I'm using my domain on a A-Record different to my MX records without any problems. Maybe it's a technical problem or configuration issue at your host.

Your solution seems right.

Any technical information?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what information to add!

Comment: What type of control Panel maybe or what hoster. Can you change the A-Type and the MX differently? It appear to me on a hoster long time ago, where i cant use the corrosponding webmail after changing the A-Type. Because he changed the MX value to the new A-type.

Comment: Sorry about the gap in replying. Different timezones. The control panel for both accounts is standard C-Panel although their other host has very few available options.

Comment: Look at MX-Entry, it should be in your cpanel. Standard setting is "No MX Records set. Defaulting to the A record for this domain." So if you changed the A-record, the mx should be wrong.

Comment: Would this be in the control panel for the original host or the new host? I'm assuming the old host.

Comment: on the old host I asume... because the domain is still hosted there. Only the routing is changed

Comment: I have attempted this solution and will let you know if/when all is well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is right.

I don't think you made a mistake but recover your zone files / restore your MX records and check them again.

Because some service provider systems automatically point MX records @ host (IP). So check those again.

And I think [this link](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/680) could also be of help to you.